# Deriving Uncertainty Relation for Canonical Commuting Observables from Schrödinger Uncertainty Relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

In case the names are not standard:
\begin{equation}
 \sigma_{\hat{A}}^{2}\sigma_{\hat{B}}^{2}
  \geq \left\vert
    \frac{1}{2i} \left\langle \left[\hat{A},\hat{B}\right] \right\rangle
    \right\vert^{2}
  +  \left\vert
    \frac{1}{2} \left\langle \left\{\hat{A},\hat{B}\right\}\right\rangle
  -  \left\langle\hat{A}\right\rangle \left\langle\hat{B}\right\rangle
    \right\vert^{2}
\label{eq:1}
\tag{Scrhödinger's Uncertainty Relation}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \sigma_{\hat{A}}\sigma_{\hat{B}}
  \geq \frac{\left\vert
    \left\langle \left[\hat{A},\hat{B}\right]\right\rangle
    \right\vert}{2}
\label{eq:2}
\tag{Robertson's Uncertainty Relation}
\end{equation}
Given $\hat{Q},\hat{P}$ observables such that $\left[\hat{Q},\hat{P}\right] = i\hbar$
\begin{equation}
 \sigma_{\hat{Q}}\sigma_{\hat{P}}
  \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}
\label{eq:3}
\tag{Uncertainty Relation for Cannonical Commuting Observables}
\end{equation}

For \ref{eq:3}, we know that the equality is reached, meaning $\left[\hat{Q},\hat{P}\right] = i\hbar$ is a sufficient condition for
\begin{equation}
\left\vert
    \frac{1}{2} \left\langle \left\{\hat{A},\hat{B}\right\}\right\rangle
  -  \left\langle\hat{A}\right\rangle \left\langle\hat{B}\right\rangle
    \right\vert^{2}
        =       0
\end{equation}
on \ref{eq:1}.
This is what I'm not able to prove.

An ideal answer would contain the necessary conditions for this - that the \ref{eq:1} turns out to be \ref{eq:2} and the equality is reached - to happen.

PD:

- I'm aware of how to derive \ref{eq:3} from the commutation relation by other means. I'm interested in what is mentioned above.
- In case it sounds like homework, hints or references are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Robertson's Uncertainty Relation will hold even if
$$\begin{equation}
\left\vert
    \frac{1}{2} \left\langle \left\{\hat{A},\hat{B}\right\}\right\rangle
  -  \left\langle\hat{A}\right\rangle \left\langle\hat{B}\right\rangle
    \right\vert^{2}
        \neq       0
\end{equation}$$
Because
$$\sigma _{A}^{2}\sigma _{B}^{2}\geq \left|{\frac {1}{2}}\langle \{{\hat {A}},{\hat {B}}\}\rangle -\langle {\hat {A}}\rangle \langle {\hat {B}}\rangle \right|^{2}+\left|{\frac {1}{2i}}\langle [{\hat {A}},{\hat {B}}]\rangle \right|^{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow\sigma _{A}^{2}\sigma _{B}^{2}\geq \left|{\frac {1}{2i}}\langle [{\hat {A}},{\hat {B}}]\rangle \right|^{2}$$
since both of them are positive and if something is bigger than the addition of two positive real numbers then it is also bigger than each positive number seperately.
$$\Rightarrow\sigma _{A}^{2}\sigma _{B}^{2}\geq \left|{\frac {1}{2}}\langle [{\hat {A}},{\hat {B}}]\rangle \right|^{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow\sigma _{A}\sigma _{B}\geq {\frac {1}{2}}\left|\langle [{\hat {A}},{\hat {B}}]\rangle \right|$$

Scrhödinger's Uncertainty Relation is a stronger condition and if it satisfied then Robertson's Uncertainty Relation directly follows from that.

But Scrhödinger's Uncertainty Relation is satisfied only if the vector $ {\hat {B}}|\Psi \rangle $ is in the domain of the [unbounded operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator) $ {\hat {A}}$, which is not always the case. A counter example [is given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#A_counterexample) in Wikipedia.

Also refer to chapter 12 of [Quantum Theory for Mathematicians](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Quantum_Theory_for_Mathematicians/bYJDAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) by Brian C. Hall 2013 for more information.

**Edit**: Based on the comment I understood that you are asking the condition for a state in which both inequalities will imply each other and both equalities are satisfied.

Let there be some states $|\Psi_i \rangle$ for which Scrhödinger's Uncertainty Relation satisfies the equality and let there be some states $|\psi_i \rangle$ for which Robertson's Uncertainty Relation satisfies the equality. If $|\Psi_i \rangle$ and $|\psi_i \rangle$ have a common state, then **for that state both relations satisfy with equality**.

Since such a state satisfies both equalities it also satisfies:
$\begin{equation}
\left\vert
    \frac{1}{2} \left\langle \left\{\hat{A},\hat{B}\right\}\right\rangle
  -  \left\langle\hat{A}\right\rangle \left\langle\hat{B}\right\rangle
    \right\vert^{2}
        =       0
\end{equation}$

But even if $\begin{equation}
\left\vert
    \frac{1}{2} \left\langle \left\{\hat{A},\hat{B}\right\}\right\rangle
  -  \left\langle\hat{A}\right\rangle \left\langle\hat{B}\right\rangle
    \right\vert^{2}
        =       0
\end{equation}$ for a state that **doesn't imply** that for that state both uncertainty relations are satisfied with equality.

Comment: You are certainly right. I miss formulated what I meant, I apologize. I was asking about the conditions in which the Schrödinger's Relation turns to be the same as the Robertson's Relation (by necessity, not just because it is a lower bound). For example, for $[\hat{Q}, \hat{P}] = i\hbar$, Gaussian states reach the minimum uncertainty $\frac{\hbar}{2}$, so I know that the second term with the anti-commutator must be $0$, but I don't know how. Also, thanks for the reference, I'll check it out.

Comment: @SomeUser I edited my answer.

Comment: I see this relations as giving conditions on *operators* (commutator, anticommutator, etc.) and getting a lower bound for *all states*. So, while I agree on what you added, I can't relate it to the question. I have corrected it, I hope is clearer.

Comment: Simplest formulation I can think of rn: "We know that $[\hat{Q},\hat{P}] = i\hbar$ implies a (reachable) lower bound of $\frac{\hbar}{2}$. How can we get that lower bound from Schrödinger's Relation? Or we can't?

Comment: @SomeUser that can be done by substituting $Q=Q$ and $P=i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and gaussian wavefunction. The average value of Q becomes zero. And calculating others that term will be zero. The other commutator term is a constant and is independent of wavefuntion.

Comment: Ok, the commutator relation implies those representations on the q-space. Then since we previously know a particular state (Gaussian) which makes the second term $0$, we are certain that we have found the minimal bound. This proves it and answer's my question. Thank you.

Comment: From this, could we gain an insight on what should be the conditions on the operators (and the particular state that reaches the lower bound) that imply Robertson's UR?

Comment: @SomeUser I don't have any intuitive insight into when a state will satisfy equality for a general operator. The only thing we can simply say is what I added as an edit to my answer.